# Precompile entire directory structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

I have a heavily nested directory structure that contains Handlebars templates in my /app/assets/templates directory.

When going into production, I want these to be precompiled assets but there are potentially hundreds of them in there and I cannot manually add each of these files to the the `config.assets.precompile` list.

Is there a way to specify an entire directory structure to be precompiled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

`config.assets.precompile += %w(templates/*.js etc/*.css)`

#### Edit

I'm also curious if just doing
`config.assets.precompile += %w(templates/*)` would work.